# SPOJ: runtime error (NZEC)

Tags: python

I tried to do [this problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/NOVICE41/) at spoj.com, but I keep getting the error  runtime error (NZEC). I code in python. I don't know why. Here is my code,

```
import sys

def unique(lines, exact=True):
    for L in lines:
        if L.count('#') != 1 and exact:
            return False
        if L.count('#') > 1 and not exact:
            return False
    return True

def resolve(N, lines):

    diags = [ 
             [lines[i][i+j] for i in range(max(0, -j), min(N, N-j))]
             for j in range(-N+1, N)]
    anti_diags = [ 
             [lines[i][N-1 -(i+j)] for i in range(max(0, -j), min(N, N-j))]
             for j in range(-N+1, N)]
    if unique(lines) and unique(zip(*lines)) and unique(diags, False) and unique(anti_diags, False):
        return "YES"
    return "NO" 



input_file = sys.stdin
output_file = sys.stdout

T = int(raw_input())
for i in range(1, T + 1):

    n = int(raw_input())

    lines = []
    for _ in range(n):
        line = raw_input().strip()
        lines.append(list(line))

        print resolve(n, lines)
```

It works fine locally with input like:

```
2
3
..# 
#..
.#.
4
.#..
...#
#...
..#.
```

Comment: see comment to this question: _2012-05-14 20:38:19 Christoph Dürr
Beware, the input is malformed. Every line should contain exactly one token (integer or string), but some lines contain more. _

Comment: @maroxe  the problem is with the setter who uploaded the input and output file ... Your code logic *may* be right ...

Comment: What do you mean? an other program in python with the same input and output was accepted by the judge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I run your code, I get the following:

```
$ python spoj.py < input
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spoj.py", line 38, in <module>
    print resolve(n, lines)
  File "spoj.py", line 15, in resolve
    for j in range(-N+1, N)]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

That's the runtime error you're getting. But the problem is actually in this part:

```
for _ in range(n):
    line = raw_input().strip()
    lines.append(list(line))

    print resolve(n, lines)
```

Since the print statement is indented, your program reads a single line, appends to line and calls resolve before reading the following lines. After removing the extra indent, it works fine on my computer.

There's plenty of room to further improve this program, both in style and logic. Let me know if you would like some further advice.

EDIT:

You mentioned in the comments that this indentation problem was a copypasting error. In that case, as sp1r pointed out in his comment, it's most likely that, as a comment in the problem's page suggests, the input used by the online judge is malformed.

In that case, you have to do more rigorous parsing of the input, as it may not be formatted as the example input suggests. That is, instead of:

```
 2
 3
 ..# 
 #..
 .#.
 (etc)
```

you could have something more like:

```
2 3
..# 
#.. .#.
(etc)
```

That might break your code because it assumes whoever posted the problem was competent enough to make an input that looks like the example. That is not always the case in SPOJ, a lot of the input files is malformed and you can find [other cases](http://www.spoj.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4566) where malformed input causes otherwise correct programs to fail.

Comment: Any advice is always welcome :) Unfortunately, this is not the real problem, the indentation is just a mistake a made when copy/pasting the code

Comment: I am on windows not on linux. I simply change this line to switch to console modes for tests

Comment: Apart from that, it might be a personal opinion, but I find the way you extracted the diagonals a bit convoluted. If you print the output of diag ant antidiag, you'll see (as you probably know) it doesn't generate neat sets of three as one would expect. You can achieve that with similar sintax: `diag = [[lines[i][i+j] for i in range(N)] for j in range(-N, 0)]`. You can work out a similar method for the anti-diagonals.

Comment: The way you try to extract diagolanls doesn't work as you expect. different diagonals have different lengths.

Answer (score 2):

Spoj does not use sys and sys.stdin and sys.stdout. use raw_input() and print.

"I am on windows not on linux. I simply change this line to switch to console modes for tests."

In any language and in any os, these works fine.

```
#for Python 
spoj.py < input.txt  > output.txt 

#If you are using C/C++, for any EXE file 
spoj.exe < input.txt  > output.txt
```

Spoj will nether test this in your computer nor using any UI. They will test your code, in a "console" and it might be a linux / any-OS machine. Use this input / output  to Test your code.